# Confused about substitution in Stiltjes integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have an integral
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} \sin (x) \nu(dx),
$$

where $\nu$ is a finite measure with $\nu(-A)=\nu(A), A \in \sigma(\mathbb{R})$ and $x>0$.
Then we have
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} \sin (x) \nu(dx) = \int_{-a}^0 \sin (x) \nu(dx) + \int_0^{a} \sin (x) \nu(dx).
$$

In the first integral we make a substitution $y=-x$, then 
$$
\int_{-a}^0 \sin (x) \nu(dx) =  -\int_{a}^0 \sin (y) \nu(dy) = \int_0^{a} \sin (y) \nu(dy)
$$
and 
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} \sin (x) \nu(dx) = 2 \int_{0}^a \sin (x) \nu(dx),
$$
which of course cannot be true. Obviously I have a mistake in the reasoning. Could you please explain me where?

Comment: Why can't this be true? Also, since $A \in \Bbb R$ in your case denotes integration limit, what do you mean by $\nu(-A) = \nu(A)$? I guess, in the latter case you mean the set, i.e. $\nu([-A,0]) = \nu([0,A])$ - right?

Comment: very bad notation, you're right. I edited it

Comment: it cannot be true, since if we take the Lebesgue measure as an example (which is symmetric), we have that $
\int_{-a}^{a} \sin (x) \nu(dx) \neq 0 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the whole integration was wrong. The right way to do it is to use, for example, theorem 7 in Chapter II of Shiryaev's Provability. Then
$$
\int_{-a}^0 \sin(x) \nu(dx) = \int_0^a \sin(-y) \nu(dy) =  -\int_0^a \sin(y) \nu(dy).
$$

Answer (score 0):

In yours

> $$
>   \int_{-a}^0 \sin (x) \nu(dx) =  -\int_{a}^0 \sin (y) \nu(dy)
> $$

there is a mistake: both $\sin$ and $\nu$ shall give you the minus, so the minus does not appear here.

Comment: Where does minus from $\nu$ come from?

Comment: @theveryanonym I'm not very much familiar with LS integration, but embedded in general framework of measure theory that would be easier to see. In your case, think of this integral having $1$ instead of $\sin$, what would happen in that case?

Comment: then it must be just the measure of [-a, 0] which is the same as the measure of [0, a] due to the symmetry. It seems that the substitution rule works differently, but I do not understand how exactly. I can suppose that - comes from the fact that $-x$ is decreasing, but what to do with not monotonous functions?

Comment: @theveryanonym: just if I apply your logic, then
$$
  \nu([-a,0]) = \int_{-a}^0 \nu(dx) = \int_a^0 \nu(dy) = -\int_0^a \nu(dy) = -\nu([0,a])
$$

Comment: but this contradicts with the symmetry property of $\nu$.

Comment: @theveryanonym: that only contradicts with the way you apply the change of variables